# How to use batch files to change directory?

Tags: batch-file

I've noticed that any time I open up the command prompt, I tend to have to navigate to my git directory. So I'm trying to set up a simple macro to take me there. I've made a folder called *C:\Macros* and modified my %PATH% variable to point there. And I've added a file called `gotoGit.bat`.

Inside that batch file, I'm simply doing this :

```
@ECHO off

:: Check if a path is provided...
SET pathvar=%1
IF "%pathvar%"=="" (SET pathvar=some\default\dir)

:: Navigate...
CD /D C:\git\%pathvar%
```

But when I call it from the command line, I'm not navigating anywhere.

```
C:\Users\You> gotoGit
C:\Users\You>
```

Toggling `ECHO on` I can see that it is executing and creating the correct path, but it's not navigating me to `C:\git\some\default\dir`. The `cd` is only modifying the working directory inside the script, not my command line directory.

I'd like for it to navigate me to the right place :

```
C:\Users\You> gotoGit
C:\git\some\default\dir>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It makes more sense to start with `(CD /D "C:\git\%~1" || CD /D "C:\git\some\default\dir" || Exit 1) 2> NUL` Your next line would be your, _(unknown)_, continuation code.

Comment: Why didn't you just tell me that `CD /D C:/git/%pathvar > NUL` answers my question?

Comment: Because I don't believe that's the correct solution to your problem. As you're only running the batch file by name, it appears that you should simply use the `Call` command. So create the [tag:batch-file], `gotoGit.cmd`, with just this line, `@(CD /D "C:\git\%~1" || CD /D "C:\git\some\default\dir" || Exit 1) 2> NUL`, _(obviously with your known default path in replace of `"C:\git\some\default\dir" `)_, then run it with `Call gotoGit "directory argument"`

Comment: Just create a shortcut with `cmd /k cd c:\git`.

Comment: The Windows path separator is `\ `but not `/`…

Comment: The point of this macro is to be able to take me to any of my git directories at any time from the command line with only a few keypresses. I don't always want Command Prompt to start in my git directories. Mofi's keyboard shortcut is a nice suggestion, but it's not what I'm looking for. @Mark's suggestion fixes my problem so I'm not sure why he commented it rather than giving it as an answer.

Comment: There are 50 million ways to configure a computer. It is not a programming question _how do I open a folder?_ What I would do for some things is create a taskbar menu. Right click a blank spot on taskbar, _Toolbars - New Toolbar_ and choose your Git directory. Give it a title, now resize so only the title shows. You now have a menu of all your GIT folders. You can right click them for a context menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments on the question, this suggestion ended up working for me.

```
@ECHO off

:: Check if a path is provided...
SET pathvar=%1
IF "%pathvar%"=="" (SET pathvar=some\default\dir)

:: Navigate...
CMD /K CD /D C:\git\%pathvar%
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the "cmd" term at the end example:

```
ECHO off

:: Check if a path is provided...
SET pathvar=%1
IF "%pathvar%"=="" (SET pathvar=some/default/dir)

:: Navigate...
CD /D C:/git/%pathvar%
cmd
```

It will open a command prompt with the directory you specified!
(If you are already in cmd it will just change the directory)

Comment: I tested something similar to what you tried to do and it worked perfectly fine! Try with the full directory in the variable...

Comment: While this works, I don't love that it prints out Command Prompts's version information.